# Run a PHP bot at dynamic intervals

Tags: php, cron

I have a `PHP` bot that gathers data about a few events. Data structure looks like this:

```
// event one
[Date] => 11.07.2019 
[Start] => 12:30
[Name] => ...
[State] => ...

// event two
[Date] => 11.07.2019 
[Start] => 15:00
[Name] => ...
[State] => ...
```

I'm running it once a day at `00:00` using a `cron job` to gather the starting hour. After I have that starting hour(which is different each day for each event) I need to run another script for each event when the event starts.

For example for `event one` I need to make the bot to run itself at `12:30` and for `event two` at `15:00`.

Is there a way to change a `cron job` from php once the starting hour is in for each event?

**Update:**
Also i can't use a cron that runs the script every minute because sometimes refreshing an event might take a while(sometimes even more than a minute) - i have a `do{}while()` loop that keeps calling the events server api every 10 seconds once the bot is ran once until the data about an event is published.

Thank you!

Comment: One solution would be to write the next execution time in any file/database, and make the cronjob run every minute. If the time when the job is executed is >= next execution time, then run the code and write the next execution time.

Comment: The only problem with using a cron is that sometimes refreshing an event takes a while. That means that a cron might run over a script that's already executing and that might result in a funny outcome

Comment: Then you can make some control like `script running` and `script ended` in your database. When the next script start running you will check both time and if there is another script running. I dunno, but you will need some kind of control to avoid the php script messing with cronjobs.

Comment: I think you aren't considering that your server can run multiple instances of your script without any problem. If you have some logic in your script that will cause issues if it is running on overlapping events then that will cause you problems regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Merge the processes into a single script, run that script every minute with cron. If the time is not the start time exit the script, if it is let the script run and processes the event.

```
// get your start time as normal
$starttime = my_starttime_check_function();
// compare it to now
if($starttime != date("H:i")){
    exit;
}
// if we get this far it must be the start time .. run the event process
my_event_process_function();
```

Comment: Unfortunately sometimes refreshing an event might take time which might result in executing the script twice which in turn might lead to a strange outcome... I need something that will run the script at let's say 12:30 and then once again only at 15:30 - i have a `do{}while` loop in it

Comment: it won't matter, the script can run multiple times. For example, let's say it triggers at 12:30 and it takes 10 minutes to process and there is another event at 12:35 the script will just be running 2 instances of itself. You don't have to wait for the script to end before it can be run again. Unless there is something in the actual function that would cause a problem in which case you will have a problem regardless.

Comment: I did consider that, but i'm trying to avoid that, to be honest i'm trying to avoid cron jobs altogether since i need something that runs a script one time at a certain time. I was considering a python script that sleeps until 10 seconds before an event and then runs itself and then updates itself to sleep until the next event but that would fail miserably in the event of a restart - not reliable enough...

Comment: cron is your friend best friend, he's honest, hard working and will never let you down. :-)